# iOS UI spinner freeze while processing background thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

From my iOS app in Swift 2.0 I show a custom spinner annimation while requesting, in a background thread, data from a server. 
The spinner start to freeze as soon as I get the data back and update the sqlite database (around 15 sec to process all the queries). In XCode the device cpu show activity between 95 and 100%.
I tried to use GRAND CENTRAL DISPATCH in different ways but I didn't find out how to make it work without freezing the spinner animation.
Any idea how to slove this ?
Thanks !!

I can't post the whole code but it is similar to this:

```
//Using the spinner here https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner

Spinner.show("Please wait", animated: true)

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0))
{

   //around 5 seconds to get data
   var data = getDataFromServer()

   //around 20 sec to process and save the data in sqlite. It stops spinning from here..
   saveDataInDB(data)

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: can you show what `saveDataInDB` does? It sounds like it might be doing some heavy processing on the main thread.

Comment: I updated the question and put some code as requested.

Comment: It's updating some tables, yes heavy processing, it's too complicated to show you. But why is it processing on the main thread as you say ? dispatch_async should make it process on another thread, no ?

Comment: Is it possible that the background thread use 100% CPU and there is not CPU left for the main thread, freezing the UI ? And if yes, how can I limit the thread CPU usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. In saveDataInDB(), I'm doing request with OAuthSwift that changes the execution thread when receiving the callback. It jumps back on the main thread and the db queries then run as well on the main thread. I opened a new question for this problem here: [OAuthSwift request callback on main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588880/oauthswift-request-callback-on-main-thread)