# OAuthSwift request callback on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, oauth

I'm using OAuthSwift (v 0.5.1) for my iOS app with written in swift 2.0.
I use Grand Central Dispatch for runing some code in a background thread. This block of code use OAuthSwift to make request to a server. But the callback of the request is run on the main thread. Is there a way to receive the callback on the same thread that the request has been sent ?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)){
//Here run in background thread
 var client = OAuthSwiftClient(consumerKey: xxx, consumerSecret: yyyy)
 client.get(url, parameters:[:], headers: header_array, success:{(data, response)-> Void in
 //Success code here run on main thread
 }) { (error) -> Void in 
 //Error code here
 }
}
```

Comment: So you want to run the code from the callback on main thread? Or do you want it to run on the same background thread as the original request?

Comment: Same as the original request, I would like it on the background thread.

Comment: May I ask why? Bearing in mind UI should almost always be run on Main Thread and anything running in the background doesn't matter which thread it's on... Interesting question :)

Comment: Ok in the callback I do other requests to server. I have to wait for the first result to send the following requests. Then heavy processing is done on Database. The whole process lasts 20 sec. I would like all to be run on the background so that it doesn't bllock the UI.